# What is a double shutter camera?

Tags: shutter, camera-design

I did a google search and came up with nothing for this question. A scientific PIV paper referenced to a double shutter camera, but there is no explanation on what this is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description [here](http://www.samwoosc.co.kr/pixelfly_double.htm) and the schematic diagram [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/270607867_fig2_Fig-2-Schematic-presentation-of-double-shutter-CCD-camera-principle-The-use-of-short), it seems that it's a camera that's capable of recording two images separated by an extremely short (e.g. 5µs) delay. You can see from the schematic that the first image is read out of the device at the same time that the second image is being exposed, so it seems likely that the sensor itself probably incorporates a latch on each pixel that stores the value until it can be read, allowing the entire image to be saved and enabling the very short delay between the end of the first exposure and the start of the second.

The goal of particle image velocimetry (PIV) is to analyze the flow of a fluid by tracking individual particles suspended in the fluid. It's important to be able to take two images in rapid succession so that you can match the particles in the second image to those in the first before they move too far.

Comment: What do you mean by saying the sensor incorporates a latch? I dont see how an image could be read out at the same time as a second image is exposed, so i will look into this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @DanZ *Latch* is a digital electronics term that describes a circuit that stores an input value and keeps it stable even though the input might change. By *analog latch* I meant to invoke that same behavior, i.e. the sensor must store the voltages at all the photosites so that the values can be read while the sensor is exposed the second time. It turns out that a better name for this type of circuit in the analog world is [*sample and hold* circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_and_hold).